# Only permit the specified IP of client to access the network scanner

Tags: networking, scanner

All, I have a network scanner (HP-1213nf MFP) with IP `10.50.0.16` in my local network, And I don't want all the machines in this network can access this scanner. I want to permit the computer with IP `10.50.0.2` can access the scanner.
I don't know if there is setup in the scanner can make it . Or Is there any other ways to make it ? thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any information regarding this in the user manual?

Comment: @CharlieRB My problem is I didn't know what can I do to make it . I already check the scanner , didn't found any set up for access control. thanks.

Comment: The only way I can think to make it only accessible to the single PC is to remove it from the network and connect it directly to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You could use access lists (ACL) if you have the gear that supports them. If the scanner and client machine are both connected to the same switch (or no routing in between them) I might be inclined to make a mini network.

You can add a second IP address to a Windows machine. So maybe add 192.168.1.1 to the client and change the scanner to 192.168.1.2. That way they are the only two machines on the network in that subnet (255.255.255.0). The only way another machine could access the scanner then is if they either change their IP or add a second IP.